# Is there any way to use xaml/c# in android studio

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xaml

I am creating android apps in Xamarin.forms now. But the apk size of Xamarin apps is more than 90 Mb. So I am planning to switch to the android studio as it is specially designed for android apps. But I have very little knowledge about Java and Kotlin.

I am very familiar with C# because I am coding in Xamarin. Is there any way to use C# instead of java in Android Studio?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [xamarin apps are large why and can they be smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36561571/295004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we can't. Android Studio supports only Java and Kotlin and we can build apps using C++ but not with any other Languages.
But instead **you can reduce your Xamarin App size from 90 MB to less than 15 MB**.

Make sure that you set in **Release Configuration**
You can reduce it by,
**Linking all you app's SDK and User Assemblies**
**Using Code Shrinker (either ProGuard or r8)**
**Enabling Multi-Dex** to improve performance.
**Bundle assemblies into native code** to improve performance.
**AOT Compilation** you can try this, but it didn't work for me, this reduces the startup time.
**Disable Debugging**\

Linking all you app's SDK and User Assemblies will actually reduce your app size upto 70% to 85% depending upon your coding and assets that you have.

[image: Click here to see the full settings]

If you do good in C# then Java could be a bit easy as both looks similar and most of the functions and method are same (If you build apps in Xamarin.droid).
Even I too switched from Visual Studio 2019 making apps using Xamarin to Android Studio using Java. At starting as usual feels somewhat difficult but then it will be very familiar. It just takes 1 or 2 weeks to get the basics done with Java if you know C#. This is from my Experience.

Comment: Thank you Viknesh TPK, now my app is of 40Mb only! But there is one issue when I changed Linker settings to "SDK and User Assemblies', my XAML hot reload is disabled.

Comment: It says - if you want to use XAML hot reload, then change linker settings to 'Don't link' or 'SDK assemblies only'. Is there any to use XAML hot reload and SDK and User Assemblies both at the same time?

Comment: If that's the case then you can Link only the SDK Assemblies untill you fully develop the app for just for XAML Hot Reload and after the app development, you can change it into Link SDK and User Assemblies and Archive your Android Project in Release Configuration. This is the only solution that I could think of.

Comment: I also think that it is the best solution